# Argument of type 'AnyAction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. unable to track it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux

I'm working on an application, where suddenly I came across 'Argument of type 'AnyAction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
Not sure which code is creating this bug, it's a huge application, is there any way to point to the particular area?

I'm importing AnyAction from redux

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any proper solution to fix it but instead I removed one of the library which was causing the issue and tried some custom solution.